# elastic search - DeleteByQuery is not working

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm using the elastic search(version -5.6.10). I'm trying to delete the docs by using a query.
The query that I get from BoolQueryBuilder is:-

```
     {
      "bool":{
       "must":[
          {
             "term":{
                "_type":{
                   "value":"xxxx",
                   "boost":1.0
                }
             }
          },
          {
             "term":{
                "kid":{
                   "value":"1",
                   "boost":1.0
                }
             }
          },
          {
             "wildcard":{
                "pid":{
                   "wildcard":"23b56ht-12rq3h-1dw18-hb13n2y*",
                   "boost":1.0
                }
             }
          }
       ],
       "disable_coord":false,
       "adjust_pure_negative":true,
       "boost":1.0
       }
     }
```

I'm trying to use this query to delete the entries by passing it to DeleteByQueryRequestBuilder.After searching on elastic search discussion forums, I found that DeleteByQueryAction can be used for this.But this is not working for me, can someone please correct me if I'm doing something wrong here?

```java
     public long deleteByQuery(String indexName,BoolQueryBuilder 
    boolQueryBuilder) {
               BulkByScrollResponse response =
                       
     DeleteByQueryAction.INSTANCE.newRequestBuilder(client)
                               .filter( boolQueryBuilder )
                               .source( indexName )
                               .refresh( true )
                               .get();
               lgr.info( "Deleted " + response.getDeleted() + " 
     element(s)!" );
               return response.getDeleted();
           }
```

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: @FranGarcía I'm receiving 500 Server error

Comment: it would be nice to get the logs as well from ES then